# document wont save using save() method with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this schema:

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    analytic: {
      type: Object, 
      default: {
        today:[],
        weekly:[],
        monthly:[],
        yearly:[],
        allTime:[]
      }
    }
});

let User = mongoose.model("bloger", UserSchema);
module.exports = {User};
```

and I am trying to save some data into one of the arrays like so:

```
    User.findOne({username:username}, (e, user) => {
        if (e) {
            res.send('error fetching post')
        }
        else if (!user) {
            res.send('no user found')
        }
        else if (user) {
            user.analytic.today.push(req.body.visitor) // push the data object to the array
            user.save((e, doc) => {
                if (e) {
                    res.send(e)
                } 
                if (doc) {
                     console.log('user saved')
                    res.send(doc)
                }
            })
        }
    })
})
```

I am getting the `doc` object on `save()` and not the `e` so I though it should have save it but it wasn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had a similar issue before this is because I am not defining a new Model I am just passing a JSON object.

Instead of saving the object you need to create a new model and save that.

Try creating a new model passing the save into it like below;

```
var newUser = new User(user);
newUser.save((e, doc) {
    if (e) {
       res.send(e)
    } 
    if (doc) {
        console.log('user saved')
        res.send(doc)
    }
});
```

Making sure you require the User Model inside the script.

Comment: It worked thanks. The weird part is that I have so many docs using the method I posted and it worked great. Idk why it happens now but.. well lol at least there is a solution

Answer (score 0):

Performing deep modifications in objects not in your schema makes Mongoose oblivious to those changes, preventing it from knowing what to save (and from making efficient atomic updates).  The end result is that, when calling `.save`, Mongoose thinks there's nothing modified and therefore does nothing.

In your particular scenario, you have two options:

### 1. Add your `analytics` sub-arrays to your schema

This is the best option and allows for finer control of everything:

```
const UserSchema mongoose.Schema({
  analytic: {
    today: [{}],
    weekly: [{}],
    monthly: [{}],
    yearly: [{}],
    allTime: [{}],
  }
});
```

With this, those arrays are now known to Mongoose and everything should work correctly.

Note that you don't need defaults in this case, as Mongoose is smart enough to create the arrays as needed.

### 2. Manually mark modified object as modified

If for any reason you don't want or can't modify the schema, you can manually mark the `analytic` object as modifies so Mongoose knows of it:

```
user.analytic.today.push(req.body.visitor) // push the data object to the array
user.markModified('analytic'); // mark field as modified
user.save(...);
```

This signals Mongoose that `analytic` or any of its children have changed and triggers an update when calling `.save`.  Note however that Mongoose views this as a full change in the object, while with option 1 it can use `$push` instead.

Comment: I just tried your solution and its working great. There is any performance benefits using this method or any other benefits?

Comment: @obiwankenoobi In general no, there are no performance implications that I know of.  Method 1 is the less likely to cause problems arising from race conditions, while method 2 and the other answer *might* be susceptible to some race conditions in the same user is updated in parallel, but I'm not entirely sure.